# Facing problem regarding SwiftSocket library version in Projects in Xcode. How to mitigate the problem?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, client, tcpclient

I am trying to utilise the library SwiftSocket. I have followed the steps given in:

https://learnappmaking.com/cocoapods-playground-how-to/

Then I open the project by clicking on Garbage management.xcworkspace. I get the following message:

[image]

How to solve this issue? (My present installed Swift version is 5.1)

Comment: The error message indicates you need to use Xcode 10.1 to migrate SwiftSocket to Swift 4 first. Either do this or download a version of SwiftSocket  that is already updated to a newer version of Swift. If I do an Internet search and look on GutHub there is already a version that has migrated to Swift 5: https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because all the user has to do is download a new version of the library from Github.

Answer (score 1):

This SwiftSocket Library was compiled in swift 3.x
And new Xcode versions no longer to support swift 3.
I suggest you to use this Library.It is well compiled with latest swift version.
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Add

> pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'

to your pod file.

Comment: does this support TCP. bcz i could find anything in the Socket.IO docs